# SELECT Latest Records on Grouped By fields MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT AnotherID, TID, TDate, COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY TID
HAVING Total > 1
```

The above query returns the records where multiple records have same TID. Now I need to select the latest date.

Above query returns **TDate** but its not the most recent one, basically I need to group by TID and get those records where **TDate** is most recent. I only need to get those records where multiple records have same **TID**.

**NOTE:** Cant use MAX(TDate) because it does not select the proper **AnotherID** field

Comment: Please read the documentation on how to use `GROUP BY` without MySQL's extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `TDate` is of data type `date` or `datetime`, then `MAX(TDate)` wil give you the latest date for each grouped `TID`:

```
SELECT t1.AnotherId, t1.TID, t2.MaxTDate, t2.Total
FROM MyTable AS t1
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT TID, MAX(TDate) AS MaxTDate, COUNT(*) AS Total
   FROM MyTable 
   GROUP BY TID
   HAVING Total > 1
) AS t2  ON t1.TID   = t2.TID
        AND t1.TDate = t2.MaxTDate;
```

Comment: it kind of works but for those records that have same TDate and TID comes out as duplicates. I need to have exactly one TID and Latest one, cant have 2 TIDs

Comment: @GGio - Try to add `DISTINCT` : `SELECT DISTINCT ... `

Comment: no didnt work, i added GROUP BY t1.TID for the outer query and seems to be working.